# EclipseLink JPA @OneToMany List is not same in differernt request of same session in Jesery REST

Tags: list, jpa, jersey, eclipselink, one-to-many

I have two entities as People and Story. Now I post my story and check my stories, but returns different Story List occasionally. I mean, usr.stories.hashCode() is not same in differernt request from the exactly same user. The database table is always correct, so I am very confused. I checked out Hibernate reference for better details, but it didn't help at all.

Model class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class People{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer id;
    @OrderBy(value = "id DESC")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "people")
    public List<Story> stories = new LinkedList<Story>();

    public People(){
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class Story{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "people_id")
    public People people;
    @Column(name = "story", nullable = false)
    public String story;

    public Story(String story){
        this.story = story;
    }
}
```

REST class:

```
@Path("/story")
public class StoryRS {
    @POST
    public StreamingOutput create(final @Context HttpServletRequest req, final String story) throws IOException{
        return new StreamingOutput() {
           @Override
           public void write(OutputStream os) {
               HttpSession hs = req.getSession(false);
               if (hs != null && story != null && story.trim().length() > 0) {
                   Integer uid = (Integer) hs.getAttribute("uid");
                   People usr = uid != null ? PeopleDAO.findById(uid) : null;
                   if (usr != null) {
                      Story obj = new Story(story);
                      EntityManagerHelper.beginTransaction();
                      StoryDAO.save(obj);
                      EntityManagerHelper.commit();
                      os.write(obj.id);
                   }
               }
               os.close();
           }
        };
    }

    @GET
    public StreamingOutput create(final @Context HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException{
        return new StreamingOutput() {
           @Override
           public void write(OutputStream os) {
               HttpSession hs = req.getSession(false);
               if (hs != null && story != null && story.trim().length() > 0) {
                   Integer uid = (Integer) hs.getAttribute("uid");
                   People usr = uid != null ? PeopleDAO.findById(uid) : null;
                   if (usr != null && usr.stories != null && usr.stories.size()>0) {
                      os.write(usr.stories...);
                   }
               }
               os.close();
           }
        };
    }
}
```

PeopleDAO:

```
public class PeopleDAO{
@Override
public void save(People entity) {
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("save failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}

@Override
public void delete(People entity) {
    try {
        entity = getEntityManager().getReference(People.class, entity.getId());
        getEntityManager().remove(entity);
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("delete failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}

@Override
public People update(People entity) {
    try {
        People result = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
        return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("update failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}

@Override
public People findById(Integer id) {
    try {
        People instance = getEntityManager().find(People.class, id);
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("find failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

StoryDAO:

```
public class StoryDAO{
@Override
public void save(Story entity) {
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("save failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
    entity.People.stories.add(0, entity);
}

@Override
public void delete(Story entity) {
    try {
        entity = getEntityManager().getReference(Story.class, entity.getId());
        getEntityManager().remove(entity);
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("delete failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
    entity.People.stories.remove(entity);
}

@Override
public Story update(Story entity) {
    try {
        Story result = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
        return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("update failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}

@Override
public Story findById(Integer id) {
    try {
        Story instance = getEntityManager().find(Story.class, id);
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("find failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

EntityManagerHelper:

```
public class EntityManagerHelper {
private static final EntityManagerFactory emf;
private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;
private static final Logger logger;

static {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("db");
    threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();
    logger = Logger.getLogger("db");
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    EntityManager manager = threadLocal.get();
    if (manager == null || !manager.isOpen()) {
        manager = emf.createEntityManager();
        threadLocal.set(manager);
    }
    return manager;
}

public static void closeEntityManager() {
    EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
    threadLocal.set(null);
    if (em != null)
        em.close();
}

public static void beginTransaction() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
}

public static void commit() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
}

public static void rollback() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
}

public static Query createQuery(String query) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
}
```

Thanks a lot for any response

Comment: can you post your DAO code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    EntityManager manager = threadLocal.get();
    if (manager == null || !manager.isOpen()) {
        manager = emf.createEntityManager();
        threadLocal.set(manager);
    }
    return manager;
}
```

EntityManager's are supposed to be short-lived objects.  They're cheap to make and cheap to destroy.  It also explains why you are getting inconsistent results.  EntityManagers have an internal cache which is surprisingly aggressive.

The rule for working with EM's is **"One EntityManager per transaction."**

Change your code to get a new EM every time and your problems will go away.

Comment: Thanks! Get new EM every time, no object cache? How about performance?

Comment: All the caching is done in the second layer cache which is common between EMs.  As you've noticed, performance doesn't matter if it doesn't work right ;)

But performance is going to be better across transaction since these objects are designed to be short lived and cleaned up quickly.  An EM is going to have very unsophisticated cache clean-up on the assumption that the GC will solve the problem in the end.

The EMF is where the heavy lifting is done in JPA.

Comment: Thanks! I thought to use map to keep the same EM for same user, but it's too much work to add parameter uid to every DAO method. Now I know performance is not a problem. But I have abandoned OneToMany List, too much work to maintain save/delete in DAO. I changed every @OneToMany List to findByProperty().